# biber and biblatex are incompatible

Tags: biblatex, miktex, texmaker, biber, incompatibility

I am new to LaTeX and am writing my thesis in TexMaker and MiKTeX.  I am having an issue with incompatible `biber` and `biblatex` versions.  I have gone through several other threads here and am pretty sure TexMaker is configured to compile correctly.  The error I get is

> Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.4, expected version 3.3. This means that your biber (2.7) and biblatex (3.11) versions are incompatible. See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentation. INFO - ERRORS: 1

even on simple examples.  I have checked MiKTeX program manager for the versions of `biber` v2.11 and `biblatex` v3.11.  They seem to be compatible according to the `biblatex` documentation.  However, these are not the versions TexMaker displays in the error message.  I have checked the version of `biber` in the command prompt and it says `biber` v2.7.  I'm really not sure how to proceed at this point.

Another conflicting issue is in the MiKTeX program manager, when looking at the version of `biber` installed.  When searching for `biber`, the Name displayed is miktex-biber-bin-x64, Packaged on 2018-03-06, Installed on 2017-07-10.  I don't know if this means the latest version was never really installed.  The LaTeX program manager gives me no option to update it.

Comment: Check the log file,  you might have a stray version laying around somewhere.

Comment: @Johannes_B I'm don't know how to check that.

Comment: What do you get if you type `where biber` in the command line? Did you do your updates in both User and Admin mode? If you installed MikTeX as Admin there are two levels at which packages are installed: System-wide with Admin privileges and for you only as User. If Biber was installed as Admin you will need to run the Updater as Admin to update Biber. The fact that you can't update Biber in the Package Manager makes me think you are using the User Package Manager. So open the Package Manager (Admin) and try to update the Biber binary.

Comment: I installed with the single user option.  When I try to run Admin versions they just throw an error saying I am a single user version.  I manually downloaded biber v2.11 and moved that file into the miktex folder and now I do not have the version incompatibility error anymore.  Now I get warnings on Empty bibliography and Please (re)run Biber on the file:(...) and rerun LaTex afterwards.  I'm not sure if this needs to become a new question at this point.

Comment: Okay, fixed the warnings too.  I was following a tutorial video and in the explanation of how to fill in the .bib file, they had left "<" and ">" around the citation key.  Removing these from my .bib file removed the warnings and the bibliography now shows in the compiled document.  Thank you for the fast responses.  All help is much appreciated.

Comment: Mhhh. Had you earlier installed a multi-user version of MikTeX? If you are using a single-user installation, you should have all the power to update packages. Downloading Biber manually does not really solve the core problem here. You'll have to go through all of this again if `biblatex` is updated in the future. Can you check if you have multiple MikTeXs installed or remnants of old installations?

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled Miktex several times today.  Several things have not worked properly, like the new Miktex console, and miktex update runs into several errors when trying to update two packages.  I'm hoping those will be resolved with later versions of Miktex.  For now, biblatex and biber seen to be working with texmaker.

Comment: It could be that you have bits of your earlier installations of MikTeX flying around on your system. These could cause trouble, have you tried removing them completely before your new installations?

Comment: Putting biber in the shared tree and biblatex in the user tree really was a bad decision by Miktex. I would recommend uninstalling biblatex completely from the user tree, and re-install it in the shared tree from the package manger in admin mode. Then both will always get updated at the same time. And after updating, remember to delete the temporary files like .bcf and .bbl and .aux and so on.

Comment: @matth Does that also happen on a single-user installation? I'm always using multi-user and install everything in Admin mode on my machine (apparently that is bad, but oh well...), so I don't know what happens on single-user installations.

Comment: Funny title. That almost reads like "Honey, I think I deleted the internet!" I hope you figure it out, I sure can't claim to know how to go about it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a version incompatibility between `biblatex` and Biber that is solved by updating.